# adzerk serving ads from adsafeprotected

Tags: support, advertising, security

I have made NoScript and uBlock origin trust Stack Overflow served ads (Adzerk and zkcdn), but I saw something weird today. Is my understanding that all advertising is served directly from adzerk as text/images, normally, yet I saw this ad being served:

```html
<div class="everyonelovesstackoverflow adzerk-vote" id="adzerk709561699">
  <iframe id="ados_frame_adzerk709561699_2368633" scrolling="no" width="300" height="250" frameborder="0">
    <html>

    <head>
      <style>
        div,
        iframe {
          top: 0;
          position: absolute;
        }
      </style>
    </head>

    <body style="margin:0px;padding:0px;">
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var divName = "adzerk709561699";
        var inFIF = true;
        var inDapIF = true;
      </script>
      // Here starts the iframe
      <iframe scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://fw.adsafeprotected.com/rjsi/ad.atdmt.com/65472/10865004/d/a.html;p=11087208769628;cod=1;idfa=;idfa_lat=;aaid=;aaid_lat=;cache=1476025155332?click=https%3A%2F%2Fengine.adzerk.net%2Fr%3Fe%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%26s%3DFznTTw6e8UZQkignHDresWHKLNk%26url="
      topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" allowtransparency="1" width="300" height="250" frameborder="0"></iframe>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($) {
          function HijackedTextarea(t) {
            var filters = {
                questions: '-ox0X.YDyJfh',
                answers: '!b6vl_mZrb8iVXs'
              },
              textarea = t.addClass('link-hijacked')[0],
              form = t.closest('form'),
              span = document.createElement('span'),
              link = new RegExp('(?:^|[^\\w\\\\])https?://([^\\s/]+)/(q(?:uestions)?|a)/([0-9]+)', 'ig'),
              lock = 0,
              submitComment = form.data('events').submit[0].handler,
              validSites = /^(?:(?:(?:meta\.)?(?:stackoverflow|[^.]+\.stackexchange|serverfault|askubuntu|superuser))|stackapps)\.com$/i,
              miniLink = /(^|\W)(\[([^\]]+)\]\((?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[^)\s]+?)(?:\s(?:"|&quot;)(?:[^"]+?)(?:"|&quot;))?\))/g,
              miniCode = /(^|\W)(`(?:.+?)`)(?=\W|$)/g,
              results = [];

            form.data('events').submit[0].handler = handler;

            function handler() {
              if (lock)
                return;

              lock = -1;

              var url, questions = {},
                answers = {},
                comment = textarea.value.replace(miniLink, "$1##").replace(miniCode, "$1##");

              while (url = link.exec(comment)) {
                var type = url[2] === 'a' ? answers : questions,
                  domain = url[1];

                if (!type[domain])
                  type[domain] = [];

                type[domain].push(url[3]);
              }

              if (Object.keys(questions).length || Object.keys(answers).length) {
                request(questions, 'questions', callback);
                request(answers, 'answers', callback);
              } else {
                submit.call(form.eq(0));
              }

              link.lastIndex = 0;

              return false;
            }

            function callback(data, domain) {
              lock = lock - 1 === 0 ? -1 : lock - 1;

              if (!data.items || !data.items.length) {
                if (lock < 0) {
                  submit();
                }

                return;
              }

              data.domain = domain;

              results.push(data);

              if (lock < 0) {
                submit();
              }
            }

            function submit() {
              var i, j, id, post, pattern, swaps = [],
                swapper = function(s, m1, m2) {
                  swaps.push(m2);

                  return m1 + "~%" + (swaps.length - 1) + "#";
                },
                comment = textarea.value;

              if (results.length) {
                for (i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
                  comment = comment.replace(miniLink, swapper).replace(miniCode, swapper);

                  for (j = 0; j < results[i].items.length; ++j) {
                    post = results[i].items[j];
                    id = post.question_id || post.answer_id;
                    pattern = '(^|[^\\w\\\\])http(s?)://' + results[i].domain.replace('.', '\\.') + '/(q(?:uestions)?|a)/' + id + '(?:/[-\\w]*)?(/[0-9]+)?(?:\\?[a-z]+=1)?(#\\w+)?';
                    comment = comment.replace(new RegExp(pattern, 'gi'), function(s, leading, https, type, trailing, anchor) {
                      leading = leading || '';
                      trailing = trailing || '';
                      anchor = /^#comment(\d+)_/.exec(anchor || '');

                      var url;

                      if (anchor) {
                        url = '/posts/comments/' + anchor[1];
                      } else if (type === 'questions' && trailing) {
                        url = '/a' + trailing;
                      } else if (type === 'a') {
                        url = '/a/' + id;
                      } else {
                        url = '/q/' + id;
                      }

                      return leading + '[' + escapeMarkdown(toText(post.title)) + '](http' + https + '://' + results[i].domain + url + ')';
                    });
                  }
                }

                textarea.value = comment.replace(/~%(\d+)#/g, function(s, m1) {
                  return swaps[+m1];
                });
                $(textarea).trigger('keyup');
              }

              submitComment.call(form[0]);

              results = [];
              lock = 0;
            }

            function toText(html) {
              span.innerHTML = html;

              return span.textContent;
            }

            function escapeMarkdown(text) {
              return text.replace(/\[/g, '\\[')
                .replace(/\]/g, '\\]')
                .replace(/\*/g, '\\*')
                .replace(/_/g, '\\_')
                .replace(/`/g, '\\`');
            }

            function request(ids, type, callback) {
              Object.keys(ids).forEach(function(domain) {
                if (validSites.test(domain)) {
                  lock = lock < 0 ? 1 : lock + 1;

                  $.get(window.location.protocol + '//api.stackexchange.com/2.1/' + type + '/' + ids[domain].join(';') + '?site=' + domain + '&filter=' + filters[type] + '&key=p0r10MZ01l1H4So8wqT*qA((',
                    function(data) {
                      // Go home Firefox you are drunk
                      if (typeof(data) === 'string') {
                        data = JSON.parse(data);
                      }

                      callback(data, domain);
                    }
                  );
                }
              });
            }
          }

          $(document).on('focus', 'textarea[name="comment"]:not(.link-hijacked)', function() {
            new HijackedTextarea($(this));
          });
        })(jQuery)
      </script>
    </body>

    </html>
  </iframe>
  <div class="adzerk-vote-controls" style="display: none;">
    <div class="adzerk-vote-option adzerk-vote-up">
      <div class="adzerk-vote-icon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="adzerk-vote-option adzerk-vote-down">
      <div class="adzerk-vote-icon"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="adzerk-vote-survey" style="display:none;">
    <form><span>No problem. We won't show you that ad again. Why didn't you like it?</span>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <label>
            <input value="12" name="downvoteReason" type="radio">Uninteresting</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label>
            <input value="13" name="downvoteReason" type="radio">Misleading</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label>
            <input value="14" name="downvoteReason" type="radio">Offensive</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label>
            <input value="15" name="downvoteReason" type="radio">Repetitive</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label>
            <input value="16" name="downvoteReason" type="radio">Other</label>
        </li>
      </ul><a href="#" class="adzerk-vote-cancel">Oops! I didn't mean to do this.</a>
    </form>
  </div>
  <img style="position:absolute;" src="https://engine.adzerk.net/i.gif?e=eyJhdiI6NDM3LCJhdCI6NSwiYnQiOjAsImNtIjo0ODczOTQsImNoIjoxMTc4LCJjayI6e30sImNyIjoxNzAyNTQyLCJkaSI6IjNiZDgzNWIyNjkzOTQzMDBiODBjMzAwNjZiMjY1ODk5IiwiZG0iOjEsImZjIjoyMDIyNjAwLCJmbCI6MjM2ODYzMywiaXAiOiIxNDguMTAxLjIzMS4yMzMiLCJrdyI6InZpc3VhbC1zdHVkaW8seDg2LHdpbmRvd3MtMTAseC11c2VyLXJlZ2lzdGVyZWQseC0xNTAwcGx1cy1yZXAiLCJtayI6InZpc3VhbC1zdHVkaW8iLCJudyI6MjIsInBjIjo2LjYsImVjIjo2LjYsInByIjo4MjE5OSwicnQiOjIsInJmIjoiaHR0cDovL2NoYXQuc3RhY2tvdmVyZmxvdy5jb20vcm9vbXMvNDE1NzAvc28tY2xvc2Utdm90ZS1yZXZpZXdlcnMiLCJzdCI6ODI3NywidWsiOiJ1ZTEtNDlmYzU0MmIwODcyNDExMGIxOGQ2NGVlYjI3OTA0OWMiLCJ6biI6NDUsInRzIjoxNDc2MDI1MTU1MzM0LCJiZiI6dHJ1ZSwicG4iOiJhZHplcms3MDk1NjE2OTkiLCJmcSI6MH0&amp;s=SKTrvQZ1nqRp5oM-6v-VMF6JXVA"
  border="0" width="0px" height="0px">
</div>
```

The interesting iframe served is too long (which also rings some alarms), [so here the gist](https://gist.github.com/braiam/88c3cf7e00d6fd0514b4eb02b2c1322b). I wasn't able to get another ad from them after loading 20 something pages. The original page which I saw the [ad was deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39944781/visual-studio-setup-failed/39944947#39944947).

Would we be served ads from adsafeprotected, or something is wrong on my end?

Comment: Reading your gist made me sad inside.

Comment: It doesn't even look minified, just... Sad.

Comment: @gelliott181 so you saw the `accountForSadImps` value?

Comment: That, `cocaPuffsPath` being empty, the `doNothing` property being false, the list goes on. How can the sad imp who wrote this live without his cocaPuffs and free time?

Comment: AFAIK that's a way used by the advertiser to ensure that the ad runs correctly. It's not malicious, but we're aware that it's suboptimal in a number of ways. There should be a meeting happening to discuss this internally in a few days, and we'll respond here once we have something meaningful to say. (And by "we" I mean someone other than me since I'm not really involved in the ad side of things here. But I wanted to drop in a note that we're on this. :))

Comment: I'm sure if you let PPCG have a go at optimizing it, it'd come back in 100 characters and also do your laundry for you.

Comment: As someone who doesn't know much JS beyond `alert("Hello, World!")`, can someone explain what's so sad/bad about this ad, beyond the fact that it's huge?

Comment: @MattDMo Most advertisements on Stack Overflow come from a particular website (adzerk).  This particular ad has content from a totally different website embedded in it, which could look a little sketchy from a security standpoint (i.e., it's trying to inject dangerous scripts into your browser via Stack Overflow).  As Adam Lear mentioned, it's not *actually* sketchy.  But it is weird.

Comment: @MattDMo I'm going to hazard a guess and say that said users are expressing that said code is bad because said code is somewhat obfuscated, and truly unreadable at best with lines such as `B = db(y, c, D)`, the existence of try ... catch blocks, etc . As such, it *looks* malicious, but it may not be. Also, it uses jQuery which makes it horrible.

Comment: @MattDMo in my specific case, it's interactive code that is not included in my whitelisted domains, and totally unexpected on SO.

Comment: @Braiam `The SSL certificate used to load resources from https://static.adsafeprotected.com will be distrusted in M66. Once distrusted, users will be prevented from loading these resources. See https://g.co/chrome/symantecpkicerts for more information.`

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out how it's using them, but the [the Gist defines an `exchList` array](https://gist.github.com/braiam/88c3cf7e00d6fd0514b4eb02b2c1322b#file-iframe-html-L29) which contains the ROT13 of the following strings: `admeld`, `googleads.g.doubleclick`, `rubiconproject`, `pubmatic`, `openx`, `adbrite.com`, `glam.com`, `yieldmanager.com`, `lijit`, `adnxs`, `turn.com`, `mathtag`, [17 omitted values], `piratebay`, `proxybay`, `bayproxy`, `pirateproxy`, `proxypirate`, `baypirate`, `gwallet`, `w55c.net`, `p0y.cn`, `ipinyou.com`, and `p0yjsrender`. Ad and piracy sites? WTF?

Comment: @MarkHaferkamp *exc*lusion *h*ost *List*?

Comment: @MarkHaferkamp How did you figure that out? (The ROT13 part). To me, it just looked like gibberish...

Comment: @PranavNutalapati go to http://www.rot13.com/, put any of the strings. Voila!

Comment: @PranavNutalapati The values indeed looked like gibberish, but the dots indicated structure, so I figured it was obfuscation rather than encryption. ROT13 is the most common text obfuscation method I've seen, so I tried that first and it worked.

Comment: @MarkHaferkamp Wow that's cool!

Answer (score 12):

As users look for additional feedback, I want to provide an update as to where we are with this. Some of our advertising clients use monitoring products, in this case Integral Ad Sciences, but also see Media Trust or Geo Edge, to ensure that:

- Ads are running in the correct geographic area
- Ads are targeted to the correct screen (desktop/mobile/tablet)
- Ads are appearing around brand-safe content
- Ads are viewable on the screen (and how long)

The ad sales and ad operations teams at Stack Overflow are very careful about user privacy and make every effort to put the user experience first.  This includes but is not limited to running only static, non-animated banner,keeping all ads relevant to software development, not participating in real-time bidding or selling our inventory to ad networks. We are not selling user data or targeting ads to you based on any personally identifiable user data.

We have always targeted ads by screen, geography and site tags. Our ad server, Adzerk, makes the initial ad call that checks to ensure a user meets the criteria for an ad to be served. Once the ad serves, the monitoring product then checks to ensure the environment matches all agreed upon criteria.

There are a lot of people involved in this process:

- Advertiser
- Advertising Agency Buyer
- Advertising Agency Creative Team
- Advertising Agency Trafficking Team
- Monitoring Product Team (multiple people)
- Stack Overflow Sales
- Stack Overflow Ad Operations
- Stack Overflow Developers

Therefore, it is taking a while to dissect the ads in question to determine how it is affecting size of the ad, page load times, and requests. As there is no malicious intent, we are allowing these ads to continue to run as we work on this.

@AdamLear's comment gave the summary of what is happening. I've expanded upon it more here. Once we have some further information to share, I will update this post; however I don't have an exact time frame as discussions are ongoing.

Comment: In other words, all the data the advertisers have access to about us, is whether or not a loaded add was loaded for a user that meets their criteria, or not. Right?

Comment: @Cerbrus See [Is canvas getImageData method machine/browser dependent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615580/is-canvas-getimagedata-method-machine-browser-dependent/)

Comment: @guest271314: What? What's that about?

Comment: @Cerbrus That is the purpose of the scripts in Question. To fingerprint users' browsers. Read the exchange at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126755/discussion-between-danny-miller-and-guest271314 carefully. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/33717591#33717591

Comment: @Cerbrus http://plnkr.co/edit/Ftm7WWCyZyPA6ScDWe5I?p=catalogue . Would traffic decline if users were simply asked which platform their OS is when visiting the site at a dropdown menu? For "a better user experience"? Actually, the OS is fingerprinted.

Comment: @Cerbrus [How Unique Is Your Web Browser](https://panopticlick.eff.org/static/browser-uniqueness.pdf) , [Panopticlick - Is your browser safe against tracking?](https://panopticlick.eff.org/) , [Client-Side: HTML5 Canvas Fingerprinting](https://www.browserleaks.com/canvas), [Pixel Perfect: Fingerprinting Canvas in HTML5](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~hovav/dist/canvas.pdf), [Why would an ad script check webkitAudioContext and webkitOfflineAudioContext?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40251510/why-would-an-ad-script-check-webkitaudiocontext-and-webkitofflineaudiocontext#comment67766969_40251510)

Comment: @Cerbrus [What is Pixel.adsafeprotected.com:](https://www.malwarekillers.com/how-to-remove-pixel-adsafeprotected-com-fake-pop-up-ads-redirects/) _"Pixel.adsafeprotected.com is treated as a malicious pop-up virus that aims at getting its malware promoted."_ , [Information about Pixel.adsafeprotected.com:](http://repairinfectedpc.com/pixel-adsafeprotected-com-removal/) _"Pixel.adsafeprotected.com is treated as a malicious pop-up virus that aims at getting its malware promoted."_

Comment: @Cerbrus [I Need Steps to Take Pixel.adsafeprotected.com off -Popups Removal - What is Pixel.adsafeprotected.com?](http://blog.removevirusnow.org/pixel-adsafeprotected-com-removal/) _"Pixel.adsafeprotected.com is a scam website that has been reported as a malware."_

Comment: @Cerbrus Open `Sources` tab at `DevTools`, search for "pixel.adsafeprotected.com" within a frame.

Comment: @DannyMiller _"the monitoring product then checks to ensure the environment matches all agreed upon criteria."_ What is the definition of "monitoring product" as agreed upon by the principals _"Monitoring Product Team (multiple people)"_ ? What does "monitoring product" do? What is the definition of "environment" as agreed upon by the principals? Browser or operating system? Or both?