# 502 - Bad Gateway in advertisment iframe from adsafeprotected

Tags: bug, advertising

Getting a `502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.11.6` error on stackoverflow.com, error being reported in my console as:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway): a.html;p=11087210763024;cod=1;idfa=;aaid=;idfa_lat=;aaid_lat=;cache=1487023847745

Appearing beneath the "Featured on Meta" section, where the various site ads appear. Haven't been able to reproduce issue since its initial occurrence.

```
https://fw.adsafeprotected.com/rjsi/ad.atdmt.com/72947/12832295/d/a.html;p=11087210763024;cod=1;idfa=;aaid=;idfa_lat=;aaid_lat=;cache=1487010387433?click=http%3A%2F%2Fengine.adzerk.net%2Fr%3Fe%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%26s%3DjObgPOFLkuCRn7R5ajZkYXi1HY0%26url=
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to delete your browser's cookies & deleting the cache?

Comment: In an attempt to replicate this or get rid of it? If the former, I haven't, since it's gone away on its own. If the latter, no, since again, it's gone away on its own.

Comment: Depends. The cause for the 502 is not in the HTML/page itself, but a configuration issue, either on the server or on a network component (router)... So, a proxy issue. deleting the cookies and the cache would be the first thing to do, then testing the website in another browser, so then you can have sure that the problem is on your router or the server itself.

Comment: Afaik, that area is for advertisements. Can you inspect the area and copy the surrounding html?

Comment: I saw this issue myself and was able to grab the src of the iframe, it is too long for a comment, if it is okay with @TimLewis I can edit it into the question (assuming its the same culprit of course).

Comment: My bad didn't know meta edits aren't allowed, anyone have an idea on how I can add that url, via an answer perhaps?

Comment: @Phaeze can you put it in a gist or similar and link to that. Then someone over 2k rep/OP can edit it in if appropriate?

Comment: @JonClements, good idea. [Here it is](https://gist.github.com/MadillJ/6f0b5c838e4463d713505f5349d89b96)

Comment: Guess adsafeprotected strikes again. Related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335956/792066

Comment: @Phaeze please include the iframe context: which ad is being served that cause this. Look for the `everyonelovesstackoverflow` class.

Comment: @Braiam unfortunately all i grabbed was the src attribute, I will try to see if I can get the offending ad again.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for catching this. I work in the Ad Ops team at Stack Overflow, and we've tracked down the ad and are speaking to the client. I'll post an update here once we know more.

UPDATE

The client and our adserver were not able to pinpoint or reproduce the issue as it seems likely to be transitory. Let us know if you see/experience the error again and we'll alert the client and work with them to find the issue. We always appreciate the heads up, thanks!

Comment: I've seen the same thing a couple of times in the past few days. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gud9o.png

Comment: Yeah, we're seeing it too and are working with the client to get to the bottom of it.