# How do I report an ad if my ad blocking rules prevent it from appearing in the first place?

Tags: support, advertising

I saw a suspiciously empty white box under the community bulletin today. It was adzerk-1757167015/ados_frame_adzerk-1757167015_6368431. The iframe tries to run a script from serving-sys.com, a non-whitelisted domain.

I allowed [only two domains to run](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335956/792066) since Stack Exchange promised only show me image/text ads. The [ad itself](https://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=bsr&FlightID=22585001&Page=&PluID=0&Pos=2119214948) doesn't seem to be something that breaks that promise, but having yet another active script other than those two seems to not be what we are aware that is allowed by advertisers.

Is there a method that we can report these advertisements without typing on Meta (as I am doing right now) or using the contact form?

Answer (score 3):

This ad is using a third party ad tag. The question you linked to touches on this, but focuses more on what is sometimes wrapped around third party ad tags. This tag is served by Adzerk, but hosts the creative and monitors clicks and impressions via the third party (which is still vetted and approved by our ad ops team). This particular ad uses Sizmek, but there are a variety of ad tags out there that our clients have been known to use, including Atlas, Doubleclick, and Flash Talking.

What appears to be going on here, is that by white listing adzerk, it's serving you the iframe, but then your blocker is preventing Sizmek from filling it, leaving you with a sidebar sized white box on the site.

As for best method, Meta remains the best venue for these discussions.

Comment: Shouldn't you have a ♦ diamond?